# How to receive and process multiple sequential messages using Microsoft bot builder SDK for Node?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to receive 2 (or even more) consecutive messages from the User after the bot asks a question.

Is there any snippet, that makes the bot wait for the user to input a message (without explicitly, "prompting" or "sending" a message to the user)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use a combination between track the conversation topic and the [TipingMessage](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/activities.html#typing).
And you timedout from last Tiping get all the "unattended" messages from the user and put together.